# Volume settings keep changing automatically- driving me nuts

Tags: settings, volume

I am running Andoird 6.0.1 on a Samsung Note 4.

In the past few days, the phone will change the four volume settings on its own! I usually keep the notifications and system volumes off, as I don't want to constantly be disturbed by the phone. However, several times a day those volume setting will change. I also keep the ringtone and media volumes at levels that I like, and they too are changed.

Any ideas what can be causing this? I haven't installed any new apps (though not sure if some apps may have updated automatically) lately. I can't seem to be able to get my preferred volume settings to stick.

Please help! Thanks.

Comment: Everytime they change, do they change to the exact same volume levels? If so, then there could be something that is changing the profile based on location / devices connected / wifi / charging etc. Do you have any such app or built in settings on the N4?